# Solving an exponential equation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

There's an exponential equation below:

9254.315 = EXP(G1) + EXP(G2) + EXP(G3)

I need to calculate sum of (G1 + G2 + G3).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about pure math and has nothing to do with Python or Numpy.

Comment: This question is better suited to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Knowing `a + b + c` does not give you `a * b * c`, and vice versa. You need two more constraints.

Comment: I only need sum of (G1 + G2 + G3), not their individual values.

Comment: Well ... `exp(0) + exp(0) + exp(log(9254.315 - 2)) == 9254.315`

Comment: But the log(9254.315 - 2) = 3.96625

Comment: Natural logs @Berk in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log) `log(9254.315 - 2)` is `9.132629`.

Comment: Sounds like a typo – perhaps you meant `EXP(G1) * EXP(G2) * EXP(G3)`. Otherwise the solution is not unique, as Mark Meyer's example indicates.

Comment: Actually, The G1, G2 and G3 values are 4, 9 and 7. and sum of them must be 20.

Comment: Just I wanted to obtain the value of 20 (sum(G1, G2, G3)) by solving this equation.

Comment: *"Actually, The G1, G2 and G3 values are 4, 9 and 7. and sum of them must be 20."*  If you know that, then what is the question?

Comment: This's only an example. I have another equations like this, in which these values are not known.

Comment: Then the comments above are relevant.  You have one equation and three unknowns.  The solution will not be unique.  You can pick G1 and G2 to be any values, and G3 = log(9254.315 - exp(G1) - exp(G2)).  The sum G1 + G2 + G3 will not be the same for all those solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
Your problem is not about programming, it's about maths.
[9254.315 = EXP(G1) + EXP(G2) + EXP(G3)]*ln
ln(9254.315) = ln*EXP(G1) + ln*EXP(G2) + ln*EXP(G3)
example : ln*exp(x) = x. So ln times exp of variable is the 
variable
So you have : 9.132 = G1 + G2 + G3
```

Comment: The sum value must be around 20. Imagine that the G1, G2 and G2 are 4, 9, 7, respectively.

Comment: Logarithms don't work like that. **`ln(a + b) ≠ ln(a) + ln(b)`**

Comment: You have 3 variables, the solution is not unique

Comment: if 2 = exp(x), so x = ln2 = 0.6931. it's not about ln(a+b). By the way, ln(a*b) = ln(a) + ln(b)

Comment: Yes, but EXP(a*b) ≠ EXP(a) + EXP(b)

Comment: I agree with you, but I didn't say that. value = exp(x1) + exp(x2) + exp(x3). You can multiply the equation by ln; so you will have ln(value) = ln(exp(x1)) + ln(exp(x2)) + ln(exp(x3)). In your question, the equation is 9254.315 = EXP(G1) + EXP(G2) + EXP(G3) and not 9254.315 = EXP(G1 + G2 + G3)

Comment: Yes in the case of EXP(G1 + G2 + G3), it can be easily solved. but it's EXP(G1) + EXP(G2) + EXP(G3).

Answer (score 0):

If you ready know the values, you can use this function.

```
import numpy as np

def sumExpo(*nums):
    x = 0
    for num in nums:
        x += np.exp(num)
    print(x)

sumExpo(4,9,7)
```

Comment: The values (4, 9, 7) are not known.